# Customizing 403 error messages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, document, directory

I've recently set up a .htaccess file in a directory where I do not want users to go,

.htaccess file:

```
deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 /upload/misc/403.php
```

This not only prevents users from going to the /uploads/ directory, but also to child directories I do want them to go to such as site.com/uploads/1/. Is there a fix to this, or rather any way I can make a 403 error for a parent directory, but not the sub-directories? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an .htaccess file in each sub-directory and `allow from all`. `.htaccess` files in child directories take precedence over parent directories.

You might also be able to use a [file match](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch) to say `allow` if you know a specific pattern.

You could also instead of using `ErrorDocument`, bootstrap all files in `/uploads/` to a php file that displays an error using mod_rewrite. Then use a rewritecond to skip sub directories. This just will not write a 403 to the error logs.